# How to enable lock screen widgets in HTC One M8?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, htc-one-m8, lock-screen-widgets

Update: turns out I was simply being blind, because I'm running Android lollipop... I do have a default widget though, which I don't seem to be able to change or remove.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Default widget]

I have recently bought a new phone, a HTC One M8, and I am trying to customize everything. One thing I am used to is lock screen widgets, but I can't seem to enable those. The option simply isn't present in the settings menu.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Security settings menu]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: That interface looks to be of Lollipop. Is the device really running Kitkat?

Comment: @Firelord oh dear, I believe you are completely right ^^ That does leave me with one question though: my phone does have a lock screen clock/weather widget, can I remove or change that?

Comment: @Luca_Scorpion hi and welcome to [android.se], consider putting the edit as an answer instead to resolve this thread. Self-answering is encouraged. As for the next question on your comment, I think it's impossible, just like Google Search bar on some devices. Perhaps there's a hack/workaround, but I didn't research it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, [as commented by Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123385/how-to-enable-lock-screen-widgets-in-htc-one-m8#comment153057_123385), that I am actually running Lollipop instead of Kitkat which means I can't add any lock screen widgets :(

Either way, thanks for the help!
Luca

Answer (score 0):

On my phone I slide my lock screen to the right, and tap the plus button. If you can't find this on your phone, it probably doesn't exist. You can get apps from the app store that customise your lock screen though.